# Visual Studio Extension - focus file after file is opened

Tags: c#, visual-studio-extensions

I am writing a Visual Studio extension.  I figured how to open a file using the following code:

```
dte2 = (DTE2)GetService(typeof(DTE));
dte2.ItemOperations.OpenFile("C:/TestFile.txt");
```

My issue now is that the newly opened file always opened as the last "tab" in the Main Window/Code Pane and never get "focused/activated".
Can someone advise how I can get the newly opened file as the first "tab" and is focused?

Your assistance is great appreciated.

V

Comment: That's unexpected.  It returns a Window reference, maybe you need to set its Visible property to true or call its Activate() method.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/envdte.window?view=visualstudiosdk-2017

Comment: I tried visible = true or activate().  Both are not working.

Comment: Please refer to  [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/envdte.window.activate?view=visualstudiosdk-2017#EnvDTE_Window_Activate).

Comment: Perry, thanks for your link.  That document just returns all the windows in VS (Solution Explorer, Properties...etc.), but I need to select the tab within a window.  The document is "activated" behind the scene, but visually, the tab is not "clicked"/"focused".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured.  The `dte2.ItemOperations` works perfectly fine.  It's the order of occurrence messed up the situation.